# obtain ssl certificate information - .net

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate

i am looking to get the data from any given domain names SSL certificate. For example I want to put in any website address e.g. "http://stackoverflow.com" and my code would firstly check if an SSL certificate exists. If it does then I want it to pull out the expiry date of the certificate. [ i am reading Domainnames from DB ] Example :http://www.digicert.com/help/

i need to create a web service to check expiry date. how can i implement it?? - I have looked up loads of different things such as RequestCertificateValidationCallback and ClientCertificates etc. Since i am new to this, i am not sure what has to be done.

I could be completely wrong (hence why I need help) but would I create a HTTPWebRequest and then somehow request the client certificate and specific elements that way?

i tried the example provided @SSL certificate pre-fetch .NET , but i am getting forbitten 403 error.

Any help would be much appreciated - Thank you.

This is the code i have written which is throwing 403 forbidden error.

```
        Uri u = new Uri("http://services.efi.com/");
        ServicePoint sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(u);

        string groupName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(u) as HttpWebRequest;
        req.Accept = "*/*";
        req.ConnectionGroupName = groupName;

        using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
        {
            // Ignore response, and close the response.
        }
        sp.CloseConnectionGroup(groupName);

        // Implement favourite null check pattern here on sp.Certificate
        string expiryDate = sp.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString();

        string str = expiryDate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a "403 forbidden" status because that's what the server returns when you access that page.  I see the same thing when I browse to that Uri using IE.  This status indicates that you don't have permission to access the Url, so perhaps you should try your code on a page that you have access to.

Also, you're unlikely to see a certificate on a `http` connection - you might want to try `https` instead.

Comment: i tried using https://services.efi.com/, but still it is throwing 403 error. when i used 'http://ipp.efi.com' it worked perfectly.

Comment: Yes, because the latter Url is publicly accessible (and also auto-redirects to `https`), and the former is not.  If you can't browse to it in IE, you can't load it from code either.  You simply cannot access `services.efi.com` (unless you have credentials or a means of access that we do not!).  Perhaps you need a specific page Uri rather than just a domain name for this domain...

Comment: oh ok, thanks for your reply :)..under my domain(say services.efi.com) there are number of websites hosted.my requiremnet is to determine the SSL Expiry date and take the necessary action(say send mail, if expiry date is in about another20 days). so how can i do it to obtain the SSL certificate information of my domain?

Comment: It's probably easier to handle this from within the site, rather than by accessing the site externally.  But, if you must handle externally, then you'll need a specific Uri on the domain that is accessible from outside the domain (say, "http://services.efi.com/homepage.aspx" or some other page that will actually render in IE).

Comment: thanks a lot:)that helped. when i tried to give url that is accessible from outside domain as you mentioned it is working perfectly..

Answer (score 6):

This works fine:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  using System;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Net.Security;
  using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ServerCertificateValidationCallback;

      var request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com");

      var response = request.GetResponse();

      Console.WriteLine("Done.");
      Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static bool ServerCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Certificate expires on " + certificate.GetExpirationDateString());

      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when i tried using my domain name i.e. https://webapps.efi.internal/ it is throwing 403 forbidden error. Actually, webapps is the name of the server in my case under which there are number of websites hosted.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to download the certificate:

```
            //Do webrequest to get info on secure site
        var certName = "FileName";
        var url = "https://mail.google.com";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();

        //retrieve the ssl cert and assign it to an X509Certificate object
        X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;

        //convert the X509Certificate to an X509Certificate2 object by passing it into the constructor
        X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);

        string cn = cert2.GetIssuerName();
        string cedate = cert2.GetExpirationDateString();
        string cpub = cert2.GetPublicKeyString();

        var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + string.Concat("\\", certName, ".der");
        byte[] certData = cert2.Export(X509ContentType.Cert);
        File.WriteAllBytes(path, certData);

        Console.WriteLine("cert2.GetIssuerName :{0}", cert2.GetIssuerName());
        Console.WriteLine("cert2.GetExpirationDateString :{0}", cert2.GetExpirationDateString());
        Console.WriteLine("cert2.GetPublicKeyString :{0}", cert2.GetPublicKeyString());
```

.cs Sample File :https://gist.github.com/thedom85/6db200104c075310527aaef63b172253

I also recommend this site : https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/tlsssl-and-.net-framework-4.0/