# How to request ssl certificate from server?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, ssl-certificate

Is there any solution to get the ssl certificate information e.g. fingerprint from a server (e.g. https://www.google.com)? I'm using WindowsPhone 8.0. Neither `HttpClient` nor `WebRequest` seem to support this.

Comment: See: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/15335595/2655508](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15335595/2655508)

Comment: `ServicePointManager` and `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.*` are not available in WindowsPhone.